# Log for what caused "Killed"? - Flask

Tags: python, flask

I've been working on a Flask app that utilizes a lot of ram to preform its Jaccard Index (Recommendation Engine)

Locally, it  works fine. But on a VPS it says

```
root@myapp:~/myappdir# python app.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Killed
root@myapp:~/myappdir#
```

from my dashboard within my VPS service it says my application when running is

utilizing 50%< but <90% in memory(ram)

Is there a way to gain more insight as to what is causing the server to be "Killed"? (is there a log?)

Comment: https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer